# Odd array value issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-week-calendar

This is crazy and I have no idea why!?

Here is my issue:

When i log `calEvent.start` I get the right date with the right time, but! when i log the obj `calEvent`, my start date do not display the time :(.

I do:

```
console.log('=======addNewEvent=========');
console.log('log of calEvent.start : ' + calEvent.start);
console.log('log of calEvent obj : ');
console.dir(calEvent);
console.log('========================');
```

and this is what I get:

***console.log(calEvent.start)***

```
Fri Oct 25 2013 12:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

***console.log(calEvent)***

```
Object
    date: "2013-10-25"
    date_end: "2013-10-25"
    date_end_hour: "6:30 pm"
    date_start_hour: "5:30 pm"
    end: Fri Oct 25 2013 18:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
    end_date: "2013-10-25"
    end_time: "18:30"
    id: 109
    location: "63"
    presettype: null
    repeat_type: "N"
    start: Fri Oct 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
    start_date: "2013-10-25"
    start_time: "17:30"
    time_zone: 4
    title: "s"
    type: "C"
    typeClass: "class"
    user_locations: null
    zipcode: "10023"
```

As you can see the `calEvent.start` display the right time **12:30:00** but `calEvent` display the time as **00:00:00**

Any idea why this is happening? :(

NOTE: sorry about my english*

========================= [CODE THAT SET calEvent.start ] ==========================

```
eventSetEvent : function(calEvent, $event, $titleName, $typeName, $typeL) {           
 resetForm($dialogContent);

 $dialogContent.dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: $titleName,
    open: function() {
        $(".j-start-time").timepicker('setTime',  MAIN.calendar.from24To12(MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().hours(calEvent.start) + ':'+ MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().minutes(calEvent.start)) );
        $(".j-end-time").timepicker('setTime',  MAIN.calendar.from24To12(MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().hours(calEvent.end) + ':'+ MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().minutes(calEvent.end)) );
    },
    close: function() {
       $dialogContent.dialog("destroy");
       $('#calendar').weekCalendar("removeUnsavedEvents");
    },
    buttons: {
       save : function() {
            var x = new Date();
                time_zone = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

            calEvent.id = id;
            id++;

            MAIN.calendar.validation();

            if( $typeL == 'C') {
                calEvent.typeClass = 'class';
            } 

            if( $typeL == 'P') {
                calEvent.typeClass = 'private';
            }

            if( $typeL == 'O') {
                calEvent.typeClass = 'available';
            }

            if( $('.error-field').doesExist() ) {
                $('.j-err-msg').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.j-err-msg').fadeOut();

                calEvent.date = MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().year(calEvent.start) + '-' + MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().month(calEvent.start) + '-' + MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().day(calEvent.start);
                calEvent.date_end = $('.j-date').val() != '' ? $('.j-date').val() : MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().year(calEvent.start) + '-' + MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().month(calEvent.start) + '-' + MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().day(calEvent.start);
                calEvent.date_end_hour = $('.j-end-time').val().toLowerCase();
                calEvent.date_start_hour = $('.j-start-time').val().toLowerCase();
                calEvent.end_date = $('.j-date').val() != '' ? $('.j-date').val() : MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().year(calEvent.start) + '-' + MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().month(calEvent.start) + '-' + MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().day(calEvent.start);
                calEvent.end_time = MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().hours(calEvent.end) + ':' + MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().minutes(calEvent.end);
                calEvent.presettype = null;
                calEvent.repeat_type = $('.j-radio-repeat:checked').val();
                calEvent.start_date = MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().year(calEvent.start) + '-' + MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().month(calEvent.start) + '-' + MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().day(calEvent.start);
                calEvent.start_time = MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().hours(calEvent.start) + ':' + MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate().minutes(calEvent.start);
                calEvent.time_zone = time_zone;
                calEvent.title =  $('.j-title').val() ;
                calEvent.type = $typeL;
                calEvent.user_locations = null;
                calEvent.zipcode = $('.j-zipcode').val();

                MAIN.calendar.addNewEvent(calEvent);
                $calendar.weekCalendar("removeUnsavedEvents");
                $calendar.weekCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
                $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");                            
            }
       },
       cancel : function() {
          $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
       }
    }
 }).show();

 $dialogContent.find(".date_holder").text($calendar.weekCalendar("formatDate", calEvent.start));
},
```

Comment: You said: "As you can see the calEvent.start display the right time 12:30:00 but calEvent.start display the time as 00:00:00" how can it display two different times?

Comment: sorry, typo : `calEvent.start` display the right time **12:30:00** but `calEvent` display the time as **00:00:00**

Comment: Are you using any plugin? If you are, please add the tag.

Comment: I'm using **jquery weekly calendar**

Comment: Can you show us the code that sets `calEvent.start` so we can see exactly what it is?

Comment: ok - done. i added at the bottom - thx*

Comment: But the time is shown in `start_time: "17:30"`..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are being deceived by the JavaScript console.

When you log `calEvent.start`, it logs the actual value of that property at that time.

When you just log `calEvent`, it only shows you a single line, correct? And then you click the little arrow to expand the object listing, right?

What happens then is the debugger fetches the properties of the `calEvent` object *at the time you expand it*, not when you first called `console.log(calEvent)`.

While I've got you, let's talk about how you can make your code a lot simpler. I'll just give one example: the lengthy function call `MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate()` appears *20 times* in this function.

Unless there's some specific reason to do this, you should call the function once, save its return value in a variable, and then use that variable in those 20 places:

```
eventSetEvent : function(calEvent, $event, $titleName, $typeName, $typeL) {           
 resetForm($dialogContent);
 var info = MAIN.calendar.getInfoFromDate();

 $dialogContent.dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: $titleName,
    open: function() {
        $(".j-start-time").timepicker('setTime',  MAIN.calendar.from24To12(info.hours(calEvent.start) + ':'+ info.minutes(calEvent.start)) );
        $(".j-end-time").timepicker('setTime',  MAIN.calendar.from24To12(info.hours(calEvent.end) + ':'+ info.minutes(calEvent.end)) );
    },
    close: function() {
       $dialogContent.dialog("destroy");
       $('#calendar').weekCalendar("removeUnsavedEvents");
    },
    buttons: {
       save : function() {
            var x = new Date();
                time_zone = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

            calEvent.id = id;
            id++;

            MAIN.calendar.validation();

            if( $typeL == 'C') {
                calEvent.typeClass = 'class';
            } 

            if( $typeL == 'P') {
                calEvent.typeClass = 'private';
            }

            if( $typeL == 'O') {
                calEvent.typeClass = 'available';
            }

            if( $('.error-field').doesExist() ) {
                $('.j-err-msg').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.j-err-msg').fadeOut();

                calEvent.date = info.year(calEvent.start) + '-' + info.month(calEvent.start) + '-' + info.day(calEvent.start);
                calEvent.date_end = $('.j-date').val() != '' ? $('.j-date').val() : info.year(calEvent.start) + '-' + info.month(calEvent.start) + '-' + info.day(calEvent.start);
                calEvent.date_end_hour = $('.j-end-time').val().toLowerCase();
                calEvent.date_start_hour = $('.j-start-time').val().toLowerCase();
                calEvent.end_date = $('.j-date').val() != '' ? $('.j-date').val() : info.year(calEvent.start) + '-' + info.month(calEvent.start) + '-' + info.day(calEvent.start);
                calEvent.end_time = info.hours(calEvent.end) + ':' + info.minutes(calEvent.end);
                calEvent.presettype = null;
                calEvent.repeat_type = $('.j-radio-repeat:checked').val();
                calEvent.start_date = info.year(calEvent.start) + '-' + info.month(calEvent.start) + '-' + info.day(calEvent.start);
                calEvent.start_time = info.hours(calEvent.start) + ':' + info.minutes(calEvent.start);
                calEvent.time_zone = time_zone;
                calEvent.title =  $('.j-title').val() ;
                calEvent.type = $typeL;
                calEvent.user_locations = null;
                calEvent.zipcode = $('.j-zipcode').val();

                MAIN.calendar.addNewEvent(calEvent);
                $calendar.weekCalendar("removeUnsavedEvents");
                $calendar.weekCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
                $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");                            
            }
       },
       cancel : function() {
          $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
       }
    }
 }).show();

 $dialogContent.find(".date_holder").text($calendar.weekCalendar("formatDate", calEvent.start));
},
```

There are additional simplifications you could make, but that will give you a place to start.

Comment: yeah, but `calEvent.end` works w/o problem. Is just the `calEvent.start` with in the obj that is having the problem... :(

Comment: Sure, that makes perfect sense. Sometime after you called `console.log(calEvent)` but before you clicked in the debugger to expand the object, some part of your code modified `calEvent.start` but did not modify `calEvent.end`. I see that `calEvent` is being passed into your `eventSetEvent` function as an argument. So what is `calEvent` then - a global variable? There must be some other part of your code that is modifying it.

Comment: but why will `calEvent.start` work? I'm logging them one after another... event is i log `calEvent.start` after loging `calEvent` I still get the right time... but with in the obj the time gets set to ***00:00:00** - doesn't makes sense at all! :(

Comment: `console.log(calEvent.start)` works because that logs the current value *immediately*.

Comment: Try this: `console.log( JSON.stringify(calEvent) );`. That will log a JSON string of the current values instead of the dynamic expansion I discussed. What shows up for `start` when you do that?

Comment: `console.dir()` display the same thing. and `console.log(calEvent)` display the wrong time. I think is something else. The obj can't change value by itself. :/

Comment: yeah, `console.log( JSON.stringify(calEvent) );` display the right value... umm

Comment: Objects don't change values by themselves, but somewhere in your app you have code that modifies `calEvent.start` after you log it but before you expand the `calEvent` object interactively. That's why `console.log( JSON.stringify(calEvent) );` and `console.log( calEvent.start );` both display the correct value: They display the *current* value at the time of the call.

Comment: yeah, u gave me an idea! the problem is when i re-format the data to work with the silly backend stuff... thx for the help!

Comment: so moving first I do `$calendar.weekCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);` and after i will do the update and call `GURU.calendar.addNewEvent(calEvent);`... thx!